# Как продублировать буквы в масиве с++

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ryadoka[100];
    char ryadokb[200];
    int i;
    int kilk = 0;
    puts("Vvedyte ryadok \n");
    gets_s(ryadoka);
    for (i = 0; i<strlen(ryadoka); i++)
    {
        ryadokb[i] = ryadoka[i];

        cout << ryadokb[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

что нужно дописать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i<=strlen(ryadoka); i++)
{
    ryadokb[2*i] = ryadokb[2*i+1] = ryadoka[i];
}
```

`<=` - чтоб записать и нулевой символ. Тогда результат просто выводится как

```
cout << ryadokb;
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: Ну, ежели решили проблему - закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ...